# How to use multiple instances of the same lib

Tags: c++, c, ar.drone

I have to extend a C program which controls a single drone (parrot AR Drone). The goal is to control a squadron of drones, but the API uses a huge amount of global variables (drone IP, ports, drone status...). How can I instanciate several times the library, without having "collision" between instances?

The only solution I've found is to modify the API (which is open source) to call fork() somewhere in the main() function, and I'd like to avoid this...

Comment: If the library is open source, why not modify the library to remove the global variables instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, this is easy to say. And for very simple, code, easy to do.

Comment: @ugoren If an answer has an easy workaround, then that might be the way to go, but if no easy workaround is possible, then a "proper" solution might be better. And it will probably be better for other users of the library if the maintainer gets a patch.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, The library's maintainer is one thing, the user is another. If you maintain a library, you should make it thread-safe. If you use somebody else's library, and he wouldn't make it thread-safe, then doing massive changes in code you don't know isn't normally an option.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just wrapping the library in a service process. Then you can run one instance of the service process for each drone. Otherwise, fix the library to take a context parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`dlmopen` can load one library multiple times. But it's limited to 15 times.
You can also create multiple copies of your library and load each of them.

Comment: I used this 'copy dynamic library' approach when I encountered the same problem. Quite ugly in my opinion, but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use macros to replace all of the global variables like this:

```
#define global1 ctx->global1
#define global2 ctx->global2
...
```

Then add a `struct context *ctx` argument to every function.

Alternatively, add `_Thread_local` (or `__thread` with old versions of gcc) to each global variable, then run each "instance" in its own thread so it naturally has its own copies of the globals available to it.

Comment: The library itself is already mutltithreaded (thread functions are stored in global arrays...).
Of course, the global variables are defined and used in multiple files, which is why I don't want to modify this API: too risky, and requires too much work.